# Find all real solutions for $\sqrt{1+\sin(2x)}-\sqrt{2}\cos(3x)=0$ within a domain of $[\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find all real possible solutions for
> $$\sqrt{1+\sin(2x)}-\sqrt{2}\cos(3x)=0$$
> within a domain of $[\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$.

This question is within a precalculus book, that is supposed to use algebra to solve the equations, for this specific problem my teachers have had problems for they need numerical methods to solve it.

If you can solve the equation using algebra. I'd like to know how did you manage to do it, thank you to whoever can solve it.

Comment: My first try, which might well fail, would be to express each of $~\sin(2x)~$ and $~\cos(3x)~$ in terms of $~\sin(x)~$ and $~\cos(x).$

Comment: $$1 + \sin(2x) = (\cos(x) + \sin(x))^{2}$$

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia then you can write $\cos x+\sin x$ as $\sqrt{2}\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: @DavidQuinn Indeed :-) Notice as well that $\sin(x) \leq 0$ and $\cos(x) \leq 0$ in the proposed domain.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving $\cos(6x)=\sin(2x)\iff\cos(\frac\pi2-2x)=\cos(6x)$. Now take the multivalued inverse cosine on both sides, solve for $x$, and exclude an extraneous solution(s) from squaring.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We have $$\sqrt {1+\sin (2x)} = \sqrt {2} \cos (3x)$$ Squaring both sides and subtracting 1 gives us $$\sin (2x) = 2 \cos^2 (3x)-1$$ or $$\sin (2x) = \cos (6x)$$

Use Tyma Gaidash's hint above to find all the roots, then exclude those not in the domain of $(\pi, 3 \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

After one of my friend contacted a Tecnológico de Costa Rica math proffessor, he kindly provided, not a formal proof, but a way to solve the problem algebraically. Here's what he did:

### Solution

$\sqrt{1+sen(2x)}+\sqrt{2}cos(3x)=0$

$\rightarrow 1+sen(2x)=2cos(3x)^{2}$

$\rightarrow 1+sen(2x)=2(1-sen(3x)^{2})$

$\rightarrow 1+sen(2x)=2-2sen^{2}(3x)$

$\rightarrow 1+sen(2x)=2-2(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}sen^{2}(3x))$

$\rightarrow 1+sen(2x)=2-1+cos(6x)$

$\rightarrow sen(2x)=cos(6x)$

$\rightarrow sen(2x)=cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-6x)$

$\rightarrow 2x=\frac{\pi}{2}-6x+2k\pi$

$\rightarrow 8x= \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$

$\rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{16}+\frac{k\pi}{4}$

taking k=5

$x=\frac{21\pi}{16} \in [\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

Thank you all for your suggestions, they were pretty useful when I finally tried this one by myself

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{cc} 
& \sqrt{1+\sin (2 x)}-\sqrt{2} \cos (3 x)=0 . \\
\Rightarrow & 1+\sin (2 x)=2 \cos ^2(3 x) \\
\Rightarrow & \sin (2 x)=2 \cos ^2(3 x)-1=\cos (6 x) \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2 x\right)=\cos (6 x) \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \frac{\pi}{2}-2 x=2 k \pi \pm 6 x  \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \displaystyle  x=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2 k \pi\right) \text { or } \frac{1}{4}\left(2 k \pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
& =\displaystyle  \frac{\pi}{16}(1-4 k) \textrm{ or } \frac{\pi}{8}(4 k-1)
\end{array}
$$
where $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Since the domain is $[\pi,\frac32 \pi]$, therefore the real solutions are
$$
\frac{\pi}{16}(1-4(-5)) \textrm{ and } \frac{\pi}{8}(4(3)-1)\\ \textrm{ i.e. } \frac{21}{16}\pi \text { and } \frac{11}{8}\pi
$$